# Apache HTTP Server implementation in C# (C Sharp)

Tags: c#, .net, apache, http, https

I am looking for an opensource implementation of HTTP in C# with some plugins of Apache e.g. Load Balancer, Monitoring and other stuff. Is there any implementation of Apache HTTP Server, which can be used in my own C# (Desktop Application) ? I want this server to be embedded inside the application.

Answer (score 1):

There are several embeddable C# web servers, but none that I know of that will load and use Apache plugins.

- http://cassinipp.codeplex.com/
- http://webserver.codeplex.com/
- XSP (From Mono) can be embedded, but there isn't much documentation (http://weblogs.asp.net/britchie/archive/2005/07/25/420512.aspx)
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/SimpleHttpServer.aspx